# why is there a linker command error in my Xcode project

Tags: c++, xcode

I am working on an assignment for school and have ran into an issue with Xcode. The error I continue to get is this

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "JSONToken::print()", referenced from:
      JSONParser::parseJSONObject() in JSONParser.o
  "JSONToken::makeInt(int)", referenced from:
      JSONTokenizer::getToken() in JSONTokenizer.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Its very confusing because I ran my code and it worked just fine, but I had inputted my files into a beautifier just to make sure it was formatted nicely (since my teacher is very picky about formatting) and I now have this error. I even went back and undid all of the changes the beautifier had made and even closed and opened Xcode up again. I am lost as to why this is happening any help would be greatly appreciated!

the code for the two functions it is complaining about are here

```
EntityInstance JSONParser::parseJSONObject() {

    JSONToken token = tokenizer.getToken();

    if( ! token.isOpenBrace() ) {
        std::cout << "Error: JSONParser::parseJSONObject: Expected
    an open brace, but found" << std::endl;
        token.print();
        std::cout << "Terminating..." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    EntityInstance instance;

    do {
        Pair pair = parseAPair();
        instance.addAttribute(pair);
        token = tokenizer.getToken();
    } while( token.isComma() );

    if( ! token.isCloseBrace() ) {
        std::cout << "Error: JSONParser::parseJSONObject: Expected     
    an close brace, but found" << std::endl;
        token.print();
        std::cout << "Terminating..." << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    return instance;
}

JSONToken JSONTokenizer::getToken(){

    char c;

    if( ! inputStream.is_open()) {
    std::cout << "Tokenizer::getToken() called with a 
    stream that is not open." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Make sure that " << inputFileName << " exists 
    and is readable. Terminating.";
        exit(2);
    }

    while( inputStream.get(c)) {
        if(charOfInterest(c)) break;
    }

    JSONToken token;

    if( inputStream.eof() ) {
        token.endOfFile() = true;
        return token;
    }

    if(c == '['){
        token.isOpenBracket() = true;
        return token;
    } else if(c == ']') {
        token.isCloseBracket() = true;
        return token;
    } else if(c == '{'){
        token.isOpenBrace() = true;
        return token;
    } else if(c == '}') {
        token.isCloseBrace() = true;
        return token;
    } else if(c == ':') {
        token.isColon() = true;
        return token;
    } else if(c == ',') {
        token.isComma() = true;
        return token;
    } else if(c == '\"') {
        string attributeName = readAttributeName();
        token.makeAttributeName(attributeName);
        inputStream.get(c); 
        return token;
    } else if( c == 'n') {
        if(checkIfNull())
            token.isNull() = true;
        return token;
    } else if(isalnum(c)) {
        int newInt = readInt(c);
        token.makeInt(newInt);
        return token;
    }
    else {
        cout << "Not a valid Token" << endl;
    }
    return token;
}`
```

Comment: Impossible to answer with the information given. The problem is very unlikely to be the code (as we can see you did define the functions in code) it's much more likely to be the way you are using your compiler/linker.

Comment: Irrelevant, but your teacher is right to be picky about formatting, try and make your code well formatted from the start not as an afterthought.

Comment: The code provided looks fine - as far as concerns syntax... Maybe you have accidentally deleted the print function? Maybe you forgot to compile the file containing it, or pass the corresponding object file to the linker?

Comment: @Connor.Littleton If you could post some kind of log of what happens during the build (i.e the commands executed and the output they produce), that might help. Sorry but I don't know XCode so I don't know if this is possible

Comment: Sidenote: `token.isXYZ() = true;` won't work unless you return a reference. But do you consider having boolean members for every possible type really is a good idea? Condider defining an enum instead and have just one variable `type` for, having: `bool isXYZ() { return type == XYZ; }`. You'd probably yet need a separate setter, but that would make up a much better design.

Comment: @aconcagua you are a genius, somehow when I tried using the beautifier It deleted my print function, and since I have over 10 files in this project I just didn't see it, so as a result I spent ~2 hours trying to figure this out. Just had to rewrite the print function and it is safe to say I will not be using a beautifier ever again but instead making my code look nice myself lol. Thanks everyone for the input!

Comment: @Connor.Littleton While yes, it is preferable to write properly formatted code right from the start (helps yourself as well), normally, a beautifier shouldn't delete any code by itself. Better than refusing a tool just for having trouble handling it correctly would be learning how to use it properly... As long as experimenting, make backups of your code - or even better, learn how to use a version control system (GIT, SVN, Mercury, ...). You get your backups right together with. Additionally, eclipse IDE has a local history feature as well. With any of these, you can easily recover lost code.